# How to calculate probability of getting 1 heads in 2 coin flips or 1 heads in 12 flips, and so on

Tags: probability

If I wondered about the probability of getting:

- Only one heads in two tosses - 2/4
- Only one head in three tosses = 3/8 or 37.5%

But I just counted on my fingers, how do you do it for big numbers?

Comment: You're describing the [binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

Answer (score 2):

For $n$ coin tosses: there are $n$ places where the one heads can appear, and for each such combination, the probability is exactly $2^{-n}$.

So the probability is $n2^{-n}$, giving $2 \times 1/4 = 1/2$ for $n=2$ and $3 \times 1/8 = 3/8$ for $n=3$.

BTW - if you want the probability of getting exactly $k$ heads out of $n$ tosses, then you can expand this to $\binom{n}{k}2^{-n}$. The case of $k=1$ is just a particular case of that.